# Linux Check if string exists as separate word (not as substring of another)

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, grep

I have a file that contains strings, and I would like to check if a string exists in that file as a separate word.
example:

string = rambox

- file that contains "rambox":

  initrd=yahya/rambox/initramfs11.cpio.gz rambox ramdisk_size=5242880 ...

"grep" command will tell that "rambox" exists

- file not containing "rambox"

  initrd=yahya/rambox/initramfs11.cpio.gz ramdisk_size=5242880 ...

"grep" command will tell that "rambox" exists coz it exists as a substring of the path "initrd=yahya/rambox/initramfs11.cpio.gz" and this is not correct.
I want to obtain that "rambox" doesn't exist in the second example. Is there a way ?

Comment: Just use `grep ' rambox '`.

Comment: No my friend, and what if  "rambox" is at the begining or at thy end of the file ?!

Comment: Just a hint: grep has Perl regex support with flag

Comment: try `grep '\<rambox\>'`. there are multiple solutions, this may work too: `grep -w rambox`.

Comment: @Survivor : Then `grep` for `^rambox` and `rambox$` as well. You can even combine the three into `grep -E '(^| )rambox($| )'`.

Comment: Sorry all the suggestions above  give wrong result if file begins with "ramboxefzegzgq" or ends with "sgsgqsrambox".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep` with the `-P` flag:

```
grep -P '^rambox | rambox$| rambox '
```

Or even better:

```
grep -P '(^| )rambox($| )'
```

- `^` matches beginning of line
- `$` matches end of line
- `|` is OR regex
- `-P, --perl-regexp`  PATTERN is a Perl regular expression

Comment: Thanks the first one is thze better one, the secod one gives wrong result if file begins with "ramboxefzegzgq" or ends with "sgsgqsrambox".

Comment: Then use the first suggestion.

Comment: I'm on phone now.. Will make it better ASAP

Comment: Just a note about `-P`.  From the man page ["This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features"](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs)

Comment: Yes your last edit is the best, coz at the beginning you missed when "rambox" is in the middle :-) .  Thank you.

Comment: @survivor try this regex `\brambox\b`

Comment: @MarounMaroun. `\brambox\b` won't work, as it matches `/rambox/`, since `/` is a non-word.

Comment: @MarounMaroun You could use the same regex with `-E` parameter.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Neither wth "-E" .

Comment: Thanks guys.. I'm still on phone.. Can't validate things.. Will improve my regex as soon as I'll be home

Comment: I would change " " by [[:space:]] this will cover also tab for example

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want "rambox" to be surrounded by any amount of white-space or at the beginning or ending of the line.  `\b` and other word boundary solutions (eg, `grep -w`) won't work here, because `/` counts as a non-word.

You could [write your own interpretation of "word boundary"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#diy), but in this simple case it's not really worth it.

For this case, I'd probably just manually handle the beginning of line and end of line scenarios:

```
$ cat -vet junk
rambox$
 rambox$
rambox $
 rambox$
 foo rambox bar$
 foo  rambox bar$
/rambox/$
ramboxfoo$
ramboxfoo $
 foorambox$
 foorambox $

$ egrep '(^\s*rambox\s+|\s+rambox\s+|\s+rambox\s*$)' junk
 rambox
rambox
 rambox
 foo rambox bar
 foo  rambox bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this didn't work, the solution of  @Maroun is working.

Comment: Oh? What test case is failing?

Comment: If line begins with "ramboxefzegzgq" or ends with "sgsgqsrambox".

Answer (score 1):

even the answer from Maroun Maroun sims right I would change space by this regexp [[:space:]] which will cover all free space like for example tab

input file

```
# cat testfile
rambox test test
testrambox test test
test test rambox        with tab
test test rambox
test testrambox
#
```

output:

```
# grep -P '(^|[[:space:]])rambox($|[[:space:]])' testfile
rambox test test
test test rambox        with tab
test test rambox
#
```

Comment: readability tip: if you're using `-P`, then use `\s` instead of `[[:space:]]`